# How can I align a map plot and a boxplot that share a y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to align or combine a map and a boxplot, both of which have latitude as their y-axis.  I've found a number of ways to align plots, but it seems like having a map involved complicates things.  I'd like to have the two plots align seamlessly, with the map on the left and boxplot on the right.

Here's example code for the two plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(gridExtra)

##Plot base map
s_map <- map_data('state',region=c('south carolina','georgia','florida'))
p <- ggplot() + coord_fixed()
base_world <- p+geom_polygon(data=s_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill="grey72")

yscale <- c(24:34)

map1 <- base_world +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-83, -79.5),ylim = c(25, 34)) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Latitude") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=yscale)

##plot boxplot   (seasonal movements of an animal)
df <- data.frame("month"=month.abb,
                   "min"=c(26,26,26,28,28,29,29,29,28,28,26,26),
                   "lci"=c(27,27,27,29,29,30,30,30,29,29,27,27),
                   "med"=c(28,28,28,29,29,31,31,31,29,29,28,28),
                   "uci"=c(29,29,29,30,30,32,32,32,30,30,29,29),
                   "max"=c(30,30,30,31,31,33,33,33,31,31,30,30),
                    "order"=c(1:12))

boxplot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(order), ymin = min, lower = lci, middle = med, upper = uci, ymax = max)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Latitude by Month") +
  xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("Latitude") +
  ylim(24,33)

  grid.arrange(map1,boxplot1,ncol=2)
```

How do I force the y-axes and plot heights to be the same, with gridlines aligned?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this - I'm still pretty new with R.

EDITED:
I've tried probably a dozen fragments of code I found, and nothing much seemed effective at all, so I didn't think listing them would be helpful.  I'm mostly looking for a real place to start.

Here's one example I found for forcing plot heights to be the same, but it didn't seem to do anything:

```
# build the plots 
    map2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(map1))
    boxplot2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(boxplot1))

# copy the plot height from p1 to p2
boxplot2$heights <- map2

grid.arrange(map2,boxplot2,ncol=2,widths=c(1,5))
```

Comment: This site works best if you ask one question at a time since you can accept at most one answer. It also is nice to show any attempts to complete the tasks and describe exactly where you are getting stuck. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, I changed three things:

- added `ggtitle("")` to the map
- added `theme(plot.margin())` to both plots to change the space around the plots (you can play with the values)
- added `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(24,33), breaks=seq(24,33,by=1), expand=c(0,0))` to the plot in order to create same axis scale as for    the map

[image: List item]

```
map1 <- base_world +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-83, -79.5),ylim = c(25, 34)) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Latitude") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=yscale) +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,-1.5,0.5,-8), "cm"))

boxplot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(order), ymin = min, lower = lci, middle = med, upper = uci, ymax = max)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Latitude by Month") +
  xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("Latitude") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(24,33), breaks=seq(24,33,by=1), expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(y=NULL) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,-6), "cm"))

grid.arrange(map1,boxplot1,ncol=2)
```